# Should I still try to get vaccinated for Thailand?

Tags: health, thailand, vaccinations

I'm afraid I dropped the ball completely when it comes to getting vaccinations for my trip. I am leaving to Thailand in one week for an eight-day stay and completely forgot to get my necessary vaccines (according to the [CDC website](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/thailand) I need my routines, Typhoid and Hep A).

Should I still try to get them as soon as possible? Or is it not worth it to do so now since they could potentially make me ill before my trip? Any help would be appreciated! I'm really nervous I may have screwed up bad :/

Comment: Ask your doctor, or a travel vaccine clinic. When I recently traveled to Vietnam, we had not gotten our Typhoid vaccine in time (and we are adventures eaters), I think they recommend 14 days ahead. We went ahead and got it 7 days before travel, as our doctor said it would be partially effective.

Comment: Just get them, both of these are not likely to make you ill. Since it's a short trip you can do the follow-ups for Hepatitus later.

Answer (score 3):

Where are you going in Thailand? If you can still get them, I'd suggest getting them just for peace of mind. However, consult with your GP as some of the vaccines take some time to be effective and might require multiple visits to the doctor. Or you might just need a booster.

I'm from Thailand and here's the advice I can give you. Don't drink tap water. It's not drinkable and bottled water there is cheap. If you're afraid of mosquitos then get the best spray you can find. Street food is great over there but if you're not sure about the cleanliness you can stick with restaurants.

If you're going to be in Bangkok only, I think it's relatively safe. But if you're going to be camping outside of Bangkok then you should consult your doctor.

And be aware of stray dogs, there are plenty there. If you don't approach them, they won't bother you.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am spending a couple days in Bangkok -> Sukhothai -> Chiang Mai -> Doi Mae Salong -> Chiang Rai -> and back to Chiang Mai then Bangkok.

Comment: They are all big cities and beautiful. As long as you stay in a nice hotel I think there's nothing you need to be worried about. The food there is going to be delicious. Enjoy your time in Thailand. :-)

Comment: Just want to add that tap water in Thailand is actually drinkable, especially in Bangkok. People still buy water because old habits die hard. You can check real-time water stat online at http://twqonline.mwa.co.th/EN/map.php?type=

Answer (score 2):

Typhoid and Hep A?  The big way you get these is by drinking the water, and *don't drink the fucking water.*

Seriously.  First of all, you should only drink tap water in your home country (if there).  Even in a First World country, you just are not used to the flora in the water unless you grew up in the country.

And, Thailand is not, repeat not, a First World country.  The really expensive hotels will tell you the water is filtered, and who knows, maybe it is.  Don't drink it anyway.

It is possible to get it from contaminated food, less likely simply because you eat less food.  Follow ordinary food-safety rules and you'll be fine:

1. Don't eat the *outside* of food (no apples, no grapes)
2. Don't eat ground meat unless you are sure it has been very thoroughly cooked
3. Don't eat anywhere you cannot see them cooking.  More people are poisoned at fancy hotel restaurants than at road-side stands.
4. Don't eat where you see white people eating.  Eat where you see lots of locals eating.  They are there for a reason.

Comment: Just want to add that tap water in Thailand is actually drinkable, especially in Bangkok. People still buy water because old habits die hard. You can check real-time water stat online at http://twqonline.mwa.co.th/EN/map.php?type=

Comment: This answer would be better if it provided sources for the claims, e.g. being used to local floar in water, not eating the outside of fruit reduces the risk of infections.